# Why value of variable c in (c=c==c) is 2 instead of 1,in C programming?

Tags: c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int a=10,b=2,c;
        a=!++b&&(c=c==c);
        printf("b value is %d \n",b);
        printf("c value is %d \n",c);
        return 0;
    }
```

Value of c should 1 as expression contain equality operator which gives 1 result and that result will get assigned to c i.e 1,but ouput is giving 2.Why it is so?

Answer (score 4):

Since `!++b` is false, the `c=c==c` part will not be evaluated at all.  So `c` retains its initial value -- but `c` wasn't initialized.  So it looks like the indeterminate value `c` started out with happened to be 2 -- this time.

When I run it on my machine, I get "c value is -349021592".

The key here is that C's `&&` and `||` operators have a special "short circuiting" behavior.  The left-hand side is guaranteed to be fully evaluated first, and if after evaluating the left-hand side the answer is obvious, the right-hand side won't be evaluated at all.  SInce both sides have to be true for `&&` to be true, after the left-hand side (`!++b`) is determined to be false, it's obvious that the final answer (to be assigned to `a`) will be false, without having to evaluate `c=c==c`.

Comment: Does It mean 2 is garbage value for c;i thought like that but i ran program 4 to 5 times still it was taking value 2;thus asked..thanks.

Comment: @Vaibhavi - Yes, in this case 2 is a garbage value.  It doesn't have to change from run to run to be garbage.

Comment: @Vaibhavi Right.  We often say that uninitialized local values start out with "random" values, but typically they stay the same from run to run.  (That's why I said "indeterminate".)

Comment: thanks @SteveSummit,this is new and valuable information for me.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that even if `c = c == c` were evaluated, the C standard says that reading the value of `c` has undefined  behaviour:

> If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined

There are compilers and architectures where that expression would have **aborted** the program, so having 2 as a result is not unimaginable either.

If an uninitialized local variable does have its address taken with `&` it does not fall under this, but its value is indeterminate. With integers it is not allowed to abort the program on common architectures but indeterminate values are allowed to be different at any instance, and using indeterminate values in operations are also allowed to produce indeterminate values.

And usage of an indeterminate value in a library function such as `printf` will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: The indeterminate version would cause UB anyway due to passing `c` to a library function